# Can we convert developer org to Production org in salesforce?

Tags: editions

Can we convert developer org to Production org in salesforce/ What are the best practices?

Comment: Please try to find correct tags and not just pick some at random.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. You have to "deploy" all the customisations that you have in your Dev Org to the Prod Org.

There exists many tools and techniques to "move" or deploy from one Org to other (Dev > Prod, or Dev to Sandbox, or Prod to Dev, etc ).

This deploy should consider moving: metadata, data and configurations.

Depends of your development this process could be painful. :(

I strongly recommends you the tool [Copado](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B3dgGEAR) that you'll find in the apexExchange

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this.  The only conversion route available is from a trial org to a production org when you sign up and pay the license fees.

If you have code/configuration in the developer org that you need in production you can put this into an unmanaged/managed package and install that in production, or you can deploy the components using the Force.com IDE or ant migration tool.